# Python import working on host but not inside a VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, vagrant, python-import

Pythonproject directory structure is like

```
--test
  --upperlevel
    -- __init__.py
    -- manager.py
    -- UpperLevel.py
```

this files in turn contains

```
# __init__.py
msg = "YAYY printing !!!"
print msg
```

```
# UpperLevel.py
from upperlevel import msg
```

```
# manager.py
import UpperLevel
```

So in my local MAC book with python 2.7.10, started a python shell in **test** directory.

From that shell,

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import upperlevel.manager
YAYY printing !!!
>>>
```

it worked !!!!

However i started a virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.10) with vagrant and added same **test** directory to it.

so if i did the same thing

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2017, 19:26:24)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import upperlevel.manager
YAYY printing !!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "upperlevel/manager.py", line 1, in <module>
    import UpperLevel
  File "upperlevel/UpperLevel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from upperlevel import msg
  File "upperlevel/upperlevel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from upperlevel import msg
ImportError: cannot import name msg
>>>
```

So my questions are

1) why it is not working in the later case, i tried the same in docker and getting the same error

2) there is no such file in my project, File  "upperlevel/**upperlevel.py**", line 1, in

3) why it is searching for **upperlevel.py** instead of **UpperLevel.py**

FYI
It looks like if we do "**import upperlevel**" from UpperLevel.py it is refering back to itself instead of going to upperlevel/**init**.py.

> UPDATE:

I understood where the problem is from.... my test directory(volume) is being shared between mac and vagrant/docker, somehow **UpperLevel.pyc** is being treated as **upperlevel.pyc** in that shared volume.

Instead of running in a shared directory i created same folders/files in /home/vagrant and it worked.

Comment: Could that be relied to the relative path from which each python script is started from...?

Comment: yes but it should search in the current directory for the imports right ??

Comment: From what I see one Python is running on Mac, correct? I am not sure, but I would say the python build of MacOS might differ in its behavior, by having different default installation search paths.

Comment: I tried both on my host machine(mint 17.2 python 2.7.6) and on a vagrant trusty vm with both python 2.7.6 and latest 2.7.13 and it work just fine. Can you share your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: config.vm.define "vmA" do |vmA|
    vmA.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "box1"
      v.memory = 3024
      v.cpus = 2
    end
    vmA.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  end

Comment: Ok nothing crazy here. But Trusty come with python 2.7.6 how did you install the 2.7.10 version ? Download and compile ? pyenv ? some ppa ?

Comment: yes got the source and compiled

Comment: Can you put the download and compilation command in a vagrant provision block and share it ? I'm pretty sure something went wrong in the way the python interpreter was compile.

Comment: i even tried with default 2.7.6 and got the same error...i found the problem kindly find updated section in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answering my own question...the problem is mac has a case insensitive file system and when it is mounted on linux, python is trying to use ubuntu mode of module reading like in the case sensitive way on a case insensitive File system.

After a lot of research found this link for docker https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/320 so those when using ubuntu docker with python on a mac be careful with your naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are running from a Mac environment, and it is possible that the Python default search paths are different for those builds, despite the version being similar.

Try comparing:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

It is probable that the default installation search paths might differ.

You can use the environment variable `$PYTHONPATH` to add additional import paths, while I don't really like this method it can be sufficient in most cases.

You can also setup your package in a proper module installation path.

Comment: i tried that, i tried manually adding the current test directory into the $PYTHONPATH but it doesn't help

Comment: What do both `sys.path` say?

Comment: well they are different as my mac has many other packages installed sys.path in mac has more entires than the one in VM....but on both the paths there is nothing related to the above path

Comment: The problem I see is in `upperlevel/upperlevel.py`, it sounds like msg is not within the scope on linux. Like it's not even a file location issue because all of them are found, but more an engine behavior... If you change msg for a class, would that work?

Comment: yes, the thing is it works in linux, i spawned a ec2 and it worked on it, but inside a vm it hadn't worked.

Comment: Try to go one step before. Open the python shells interactively and try importing from there. Using TAB you can explore the properties of your modules, allowing you to track down what might be happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149175/discussion-between-wudpecker-and-fabien).